# how can I reformate specific words in a string?

Tags: java, string

I have this sequence of code to try and format a math calculation

```
//TODO add PI
     final double PIE=Math.PI;
    System.out.println(PIE);
    String pieThing="2PI2PI";
    System.out.println(pieThing);
    //TODO check for indexes before a thing. Helpful for moving index line and Syntax check
    if(pieThing.indexOf("PI")>0)
    {
        if(pieThing.charAt(pieThing.indexOf("PI")-1)=='2')//<--- This is annoying use a switch
        {
            StringBuilder pieThingBuilder=new StringBuilder(pieThing);
            pieThingBuilder.insert(pieThing.indexOf("PI"),"*");
            pieThing=pieThingBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pieThing);
    pieThing=pieThing.replace("PI",Double.toString(PIE));
    System.out.println(pieThing);
```

But it will only run once, how can I have it check, find and convert all "PI"s to have a "*" if there's a 2 behind them?

Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Have a look at `String.replaceAll()`